# Prove $R/M$ is a division ring for a non-commutative ring $R$ with max ideal $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove that $R/M$ is a division ring if $M$ is a maximal ideal of a non-commutative ring $R$. I tried by using similar arguments as in $R$ commutative. But the proof that $R/M$ is a field if $M$ is maximal fails if $R$ is non-commutative.

Comment: All you can say in the general case is that $\;R/M\;$ is **a simple** ring.

Comment: However, if R is a unital ring and I is atwo-sided ideal of R, then R/I is a division ring iff I is maximal for the inclusion in the set of the right-sided ideals of R and is maximal for the inclusion in the set of the left-sided ideals of R.

Comment: @DonAntonio : I came across this example. Given $R$ is a division ring (not necessarily commutative). Define $R[\gamma]=\Big\{a+b\gamma\;|\;a,b\in R\;,\;\gamma^2=1\;,\;a\gamma=\gamma a\:\forall a\in R\;,\;a+b\gamma=c+d\gamma\iff a=c \;\&\;c=d\Big\}$. Then the ideals $\langle1-\gamma\rangle$ and $\langle1+\gamma\rangle$ are maximal in $R[\gamma]$ $\Big((1+\gamma)$ and $(1-\gamma)$ are units in $R[\gamma]\Big)$. $R[\gamma]/\langle1-\gamma\rangle$ is a division ring as $R[\gamma]/\langle1-\gamma\rangle\cong R$ and $R[\gamma]$ is not commutative.

Comment: @DonAntonio : My question is " Is commutativity of ring $R$ necessary for an ideal to be maximal in $R$? "

Comment: @Watson how to prove that R/I is a divison ring if I is maximal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't true.  For instance, if $k$ is a division ring, then the ring $M_n(k)$ of $n\times n$ matrices over $k$ has no nontrivial two-sided ideals, so $0$ is a maximal ideal in this ring. But if $n>1$, then $M_n(k)/0\cong M_n(k)$ is not a division ring.