# Show that $R/M$ is a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity. If the set of all non-invertible elements form an ideal $M$, show that $R/M$ is a division ring.
>
> Also show that in this case for each $r\in R$, either $r$ or $1-r$ is invertible.

I tried as follows:
Let $a+M\in R/M$ we must prove that there is exist $x+M\in R/M$ such that $(a+M)(x+M)=1+M$ so $ax+M=1+M$ so $ax=1$ so $a$ is invertible, but $R$ does not necessarily have units, what can I do?

Comment: Is $R$ a commutative ring?. I think it must be.

Comment: @Charter No, the problem does not say.

Comment: it can be proved that $M$ is maximal and then $R/M$ is a simple ring. I don't know how to conclude from this that $R/M$ is a division ring.

Comment: I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927580/r-m-is-a-division-ring so your ring has to be commutative otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: Yes, it's true, maybe they were wrong on this problem...

Comment: @Charter No, the statement is just fine. If the nonunits form an ideal, that ideal is the unique maximal  left/right/two-sided ideal, and the quotient is a division ring.

Comment: Yeah you're right but if $ M $ were an arbitrary maximal ideal the quotient isn't always a division ring. Anyway I didn't delete my answer because answering the question I found a simpler proof about a characterization of local rings :D

Comment: @Charter so the comment was about the user's first comment, I see. I wasn't sure if you were talking about the post or not. But the characterization you're talking about can be extended to work for noncommutative local rings. It seems like you really ought to do that rather than add this unnecessary condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+M(\neq M)\in R/M\implies a\notin M\implies a$ is an invertible element $\implies \exists b\in R$ such that $ab=ba=1$.

So $(a+M)(b+M)=(b+M)(a+M)=1+M$

**Second Part**:

Suppose neither $r$ nor $1-r$ is invertible. Then $r,1-r\in M\implies 1\in M$ which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:R\rightarrow R/M$ be the projection. Suppose that $p(a)\neq 0$ this implies that $a$ is not in $M$, thus $a$ is invertible, there exists $b,c$ such that $ab=1, ca=1$, this implies that $p(a)p(b)=1=p(c)p(a)$

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, $R$ has to be commutative. So assuming this I going to prove that $R/M$ is a simple ring (which is equivalent to be a field, why?).

Lemma: $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Proof: Suppose that $M$ is not maximal, then there is a proper ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $M\subset I$. So there exists $r\in I\setminus M$. If $r$ is a unit then $I=R$, contradiction, so $r$ is a non-unit and thus $r\in M$, contradiction again. Therefore $M$ is maximal.

Now, we apply the correspondence theorem for ideals which states that

Any ideal of $R/M$ must be of the form $J/M$ for some ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $J\supseteq M$.

But since $M$ is maximal, $J=M$ or $J=R$, then all the ideals of $R$ are $\{0\}$ and $R/M$. Hence, $R/M$ is simple.

Finally, if both $r$ and $1-r$ are non-units, then $r+(1-r)=1\in M$, so $M=R$, contradicting that $M$ is maximal. This means that either $r$ or $1−r$ is invertible.