# Maximal right ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

A question on basic understanding.

If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a maximal two-sided ideal of $R$, then we know $R/I$ is a field. My question is what, if anything, can we conclude if $I$ is merely a maximal one-sided ideal? Do we obtain a division ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a maximal two-sided ideal of $R$, then we know $R/I$ is a field.

No, that is [not true.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1927583/29335) You only know it is a simple ring, which means it has exactly two two-sided ideals (both trivial.)

> what, if anything, can we conclude if $I$ is merely a maximal one-sided ideal?

If $I$ is a maximal right ideal, you can say that $R/I$ is a simple right $R$ module, which means it has exactly two submodules (both trivial.)

If you have a two-sided $I$ ideal *which happens* to be maximal as a right ideal, then you *can* say that $R/I$ is a division ring.