# What can we say about a non-commutative ring modulo a max ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose that $R$ is a non-commutative unital ring and $M$ is a two-sided maximal ideal of $R$. What can we say about $R/M$? How close can we get to the analogous result that $R/M$ is a field as in the commutative case?

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927580

Comment: $R/M$ has no nontrivial (different from $0$ and $R/M$) two-sided ideals.

Comment: You can say that $R/M$ is a simple ring. If it is Artinian, then it is a matrix ring over a division ring, but the structure of simple non-Artinian rings is much more complicated.

Comment: Must be a duplicate somewhere, but I had a hard time finding it...