# A question about a maximal ideal $M$ in a non-commutative ring $R$ having identity but without zero divisors and its quotient ring $R/M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noncommutative-algebra

> Does every maximal ideal $M$ in a non-commutative ring $R$ having identity but without zero divisors make $R/M$ a division ring?

The question is equivalent to "Does there exist a non-commutative and simple domain?".

It is a little difficult to construct the example. Thank rschwieb.

Comment: Try to prove it...

Comment: @Wuestenfux.........(╥_╥)

Comment: Try to see what kind of property $R/M$ has in general when $M$ is maximal, and then what does it add that $R$ is reduced. (For instance, what is the difference with a case such as $R=M_n(K)$ and $M=\{0\}$?)

Comment: For future visitors, I wanted to collect a list of similar posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070401/what-can-we-say-about-a-non-commutative-ring-modulo-a-max-ideal?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927580/prove-r-m-is-a-division-ring-for-a-non-commutative-ring-r-with-max-ideal-m?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There exist noncommutative domains which are simple but which are also not division rings.  The most famous is probably the [first Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra).

In any such ring, the zero ideal is maximal, but the quotient is not a division ring.

Comment: Here's the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=8&H=3&L=2)