# The maximal ideals of $M_3 (\mathbb {Z})$

Tags: ideals, noncommutative-algebra

What are the two sided maximal ideals of $M_3 (\mathbb {Z})$?

Is the quotient by a maximal ideal a field in case of noncommutative rings?

Comment: No, it is not. For instance, $\{0\}$ is *the* maximal two-sided ideal of $M_n(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: The two-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$ (where $R$ is a ring) are all of the form $M_n(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: Can you point me to a detailed solution or give me some hints? @anon

Comment: Google "two-sided ideals of matrix rings."

Comment: Your second question is also a duplicate, although a good dupe is hard to find. You could check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927580/29335 to see why the answer is "no."  Such a quotient will always be a simple ring, but not always a field.